# Can't find window "Memory" in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, native-code

I'm trying to debug a native C++ application and need to see the memory alignment in structures.
I wanted to use the debugging window "Memory", but I can't find it where it should be.
As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I enabled "address-level debugging", but it's still not there.

I'm using the Ultimate Edition, so this shouldn't be the problem!

Comment: Have you started your debugging session?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, I have. By the way: I'm using the german version (if that matters)

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-M-1` (or 2, 3, 4 etc also) when debugging - adress-level debugging has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @stijn: Thanks - the shortcut worked. Strange that I can't access it from the menu bar...

Comment: It is hidden in an *extra* sub-menu because there are four of them.  Use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1.

Comment: @HansPassant: It's just not there - I double checked! (Maybe you can customize these things and some of my settings are messed up - I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the memory window while the debugger is running.
So instead of clicking "Run" try clicking "Step into", or make a breakpoint somewhere so the debugger doesn't terminate automatically. Then look under Debug -> Windows -> Memory.